# Не работает SQL запрос в цикле while. Можно ли писать sql запросы в цикле?

Tags: php

Я прогоняю в цикле первую таблицу db_jobs по условиям и с нее формирую массив
Внутри этого цикла мне нужно проверить  в другой таблице db_jobs_use на количество.
Но цикл останавливается. Я новичок поэтому и пишу в разделе для новичков. 
Кто знает правильно ли это sql запрос внутри цикла и как это правильно записать?

```
$pay_job = array();
$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `db_jobs` WHERE `accept` = '1' ");
if($db->NumRows() == 0){
  array_push($pay_job, 0);
}else{
  while($datas = $db->FetchArray()) {
    $times_job = floor($datas['job_money']/$datas['pay']);
    $for_id_j = $datas['id'];
    $db->Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `db_jobs_use` WHERE `id_job` = '$for_id_j' ");
    $forro = $db->FetchRow();
    $times_job = $times_job - $forro;
    if ($times_job <1) {
      array_push($pay_job, $datas['id']);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Писать можно, но вы сильно нагружаете базу. Сделаете одним запросом через `LEFT JOIN` и это упростит всю задачу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ - я правда не знаю что такое left join
Вы вот говорите что писать можно - но не работает. цикл сразу обрывается на первом же цикле

Comment: Почитайте в интернете. Там полно информации. И никогда не подставляйте переменные напрямую в запрос. Используйте подготовленные запросы (prepared statments)

Comment: Проблема здесь в классе $db. Это очень плохой класс, и использовать его ни в коем случае не следует. И остановка цикла, небезопасные запросы - все проблемы вызваны этим классом. Вместо него следует использовать PDO с подготовленными выражениями.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял структуру базы то вот запрос который отдаст вам кол-во активных работ:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM `db_jobs_use` 
 LEFT JOIN `db_jobs` ON `db_jobs`.`id` = `db_jobs_use`.`id_job`
WHERE `db_jobs`.`accept` = '1' 
GROUP BY `db_jobs_use`.`id_job`
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за реальную помощь, но возможно я не так понял:
или не так объяснил. я заменил свое выражение на Ваше - и компьютер завис на 2 минуты думал долго. возможно это из за того как говорили люди выше что нельзя в одном цикле делать запрос.. а как объединить одним запросом чтобы одновременно брать результаты из двух баз. к сожалению IQ не хватает. с одной таблицы db_jobs нужно брать id  а из второй 
 db_jobs_use количество работ на проверке

Comment: Не за что, этот запрос выдаст сразу все что вы выполняете из своего запроса и цикла. После его выполнения цикл не нужен. Если вам нужны названия самих работ, добавьте еще в первом select названия к примеру `SELECT COUNT(*), db_jobs.job_name ...` Т.е. вы выполните сразу все одним запросом  к базе. Не нужно делать дополнительных запросов. Они и вешают вам систему.

Answer (score 0):

Такой запрос:

```
SELECT J.id
  FROM db_jobs J
  LEFT JOIN db_jobs_use U ON J.id = U.id_job
 WHERE J.accept = 1
 GROUP BY J.id,J.job_money,J.pay
HAVING floor(J.job_money/J.pay) - COUNT(U.id_job) < 1
```

Выполнит за вас всю работу, которую вы делали в PHP, т.е. даст id только тех job, для которых количество записей в jobs_use больше либо равно job_money/pay. И тогда вам его надо один раз выполнить и выбрать записи буквально циклом `while($datas = $db->FetchArray()) { array_push($pay_job, $datas['id']); }`
Правда вы по нему не сможете проверить свое первое условие, что в jobs вообще нет ни одной записи с accept=1. Это лучше всего проверить запросом `select 1 from db_jobs where accept=1 limit 1`. Он вернет 1 только в случае если в таблице есть как минимум одна запись, что нам и требуется. И при этом не будет предварительно читать все записи с accept=1

P.S. запрос написан в предположении, что ваша БД поддерживает функцию floor. Большинство СУБД ее поддерживают. Но если вдруг ее нет (у вас SQLite или что нибудь экзотическое), надо будет найти ее эквивалент.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! вы очень помогаете! Удачи Вам во всех Ваших делах. буду разбираться. Честно первый раз вижу чтобы в запросе так вот все делали! очень интересно разобраться что к чему.. правда я не понял что такое J или U  в запросе..

Comment: @ВиталийЧилингиров J и U это _алиасы_. Видите, они стоят после имени таблицы (в from и join) это означает, что во всем остальном запросе к полям этих таблиц можно обращаться не по имени таблицы, а по этим алиасам. Так просто запрос короче выходит (ну и позволяет использовать одну таблицу несколько раз с разными именами, если потребуется)

Comment: Все! буду учить!) это интересно и очень элегантно записано в коде.. только что сделал Ваш запрос, но проблемка вылезла. Искал что не так.. Не учитывает Чтобы подсчитать в таблице U  с условием что U.pay = 0.
У меня этого условия нет в таблице, возможно я не подумал об этом.

Comment: @ВиталийЧилингиров Определитесь, что именно должно происходить в этом случае и либо отфильтруйте лишнее в where, либо в расчете что нибудь с ним сделайте, вроде `case when pay=0 then 1 else pay end` (что бы 1 его считать)